# CSS Issue: first-child, last-child and only-child pseudo classes doesn't work correctly on lists

Tags: html, css

The following pseudo classes doesn't work as I expected:

- `first-child`: The firsts *a* of each *div* should have a red backgroud.
- `last-child`: The last *a* of each *div* should have a blue backgroud.
- `only-child`: Only the *a* of the last *div* should have the grey background, the border radius at 60% and the text color to white.

The *a* in the middle of each *div* ("Two") should have a green background.

As I said before, It doesn't work as I wanted it to because as a result it appears all *a* with grey background, border radius at 60% and white text (basically with the only-child propeties).

What should I change in my code?

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:first-child {
  background-color: red;
}

a:last-child {
  background-color: blue;
}

a:only-child {
  border-radius: 60%;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
      <!-- Background should be RED and Yellow text -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <!-- Background should be GREEN and Yellow text -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a>
      <!-- Background should be BLUE and Yellow text -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
      <!-- Background should be RED and Yellow text -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <!-- Background should be GREEN and Yellow text -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a>
      <!-- Background should be BLUE and Yellow text -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">One</a>
      <!-- Background should be RED and Yellow text -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Two</a>
      <!-- Background should be GREEN and Yellow text -->
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Three</a>
      <!-- Background should be BLUE and Yellow text -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Last one</a>
      <!-- Background should be GREY, border radius at 60% and White text -->
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You understood in a wrong way  the a here is child of `li`.
  -Means what ever you want to apply apply to child of `ul` which is `li`.
- `ul li:fisrt-child`.
  -`ul li:last-child`.
  -`ul li:only-child`.

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:first-child a {
  background-color: red;
}

ul li:last-child a {
  background-color: blue;
}

ul li:only-child a {
  border-radius: 60%;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a>
        <!-- Background should be RED and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        <!-- Background should be GREEN and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a>
        <!-- Background should be BLUE and Yellow text -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a>
        <!-- Background should be RED and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        <!-- Background should be GREEN and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a>
        <!-- Background should be BLUE and Yellow text -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a>
        <!-- Background should be RED and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        <!-- Background should be GREEN and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a>
        <!-- Background should be BLUE and Yellow text -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Last one</a>
        <!-- Background should be GREY, border radius at 60% and White text -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `first-child` `last-child` `only-child` for the `li` not for `a`

```css
li {
  list-style: none;
}

a {
  padding: 10px;
  display: inline-block;
  background-color: green;
  color: yellow;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul li:first-child a {
  background-color: red;
}

ul li:last-child a {
  background-color: blue;
}

ul li:only-child a {
  border-radius: 60%;
  background-color: grey;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a>
        <!-- Background should be RED and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        <!-- Background should be GREEN and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a>
        <!-- Background should be BLUE and Yellow text -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a>
        <!-- Background should be RED and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        <!-- Background should be GREEN and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a>
        <!-- Background should be BLUE and Yellow text -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">One</a>
        <!-- Background should be RED and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Two</a>
        <!-- Background should be GREEN and Yellow text -->
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">Three</a>
        <!-- Background should be BLUE and Yellow text -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Last one</a>
        <!-- Background should be GREY, border radius at 60% and White text -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```